# Mootools reuse same function on multiple instances with something like the each function

Tags: mootools, bind

I'm using the mootools wall plugin, Its working well in my application, however if I add multiple (image) walls it only works for one wall ::: My understanding of scripting is not good enough to add a each function or similar :::
I need to "bind" the code below to say 2 divs like this :::

My First wall:

```
<div id="viewport">
<div id="wall">
```

Second wall:

```
<div id="viewport">
<div id="wall_02">
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
var wallIMAGES = new Wall( "wall", {

                    "width": scArray[1],
                    "height": scArray[1],

                    callOnUpdate: function(items){
                        items.each(function(e, i){
                            var el = wall[counterFluid];
                            if (el) {
                                var a = new Element("img[width="+scArray[1]+"][height="+scArray[1]+"][src={thumb}]".substitute(el));
                                    a.inject(e.node).set("opacity", 0).fade("in");
                                    e.node.store("tubeObject", el);
                            }
                            counterFluid++;
                            // Reset counter
                            if( counterFluid >= scArray[10].length) counterFluid = 0;
                        })
                    }

    });
        wallIMAGES.initWall();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var my_wall_ids = ['wall', 'wall_02'];
var myWalls = [];
var baseWallOptions = {
        "width": scArray[1],
        "height": scArray[1],
        callOnUpdate: function(items){
            items.each(function(e, i){
                var el = wall[counterFluid];
                if (el) {
                    var a = new Element("img[width="+scArray[1]+"][height="+scArray[1]+"][src={thumb}]".substitute(el));
                    a.inject(e.node).set("opacity", 0).fade("in");
                    e.node.store("tubeObject", el);
                }
                counterFluid++;
                // Reset counter
                if( counterFluid >= scArray[10].length) {counterFluid = 0;}
            }); // end items.each
        }
}
for (var i=0;i<my_wall_ids.length;i++){
    var id = my_wall_ids[i];
    var wallOptions = baseWallOptions;
    // if your customization was something like changing
    // the height , but only on the 'wall' element
    if (id === 'wall') {
        wallOptions.height = 400;
    }
    myWalls[i] = new Wall(id, wallOptions);
    myWalls[i].initWall();
}
```

Comment: This works well @artlung, THX ::: I can now use it & build further on the options :::

Answer (score 0):

If you read [Wall's documentation](http://wall.plasm.it/documentation/), you'll notice that, just like most other classes, the first argument it takes is an element `id`.

So, if your initialization code states

```
new Wall("wall", { …
```

…then it will be applied to the element that has the id "wall".

You could simply duplicate your code and use one with "wall", the other one with "wall_02". However, that would be bad practice. Indeed, if you later wanted to change some options, you'd have to do it in two distinct blocks, and they would probably get out of sync.

If your only difference lies in the target `id`, and the options are to be shared, simply store the options object (second parameter to the `Wall` class) in a variable and use it twice! That is:

```
var wallOptions =  { width: … };

var wallImages = new Wall("wall", wallOptions),
    wallImages2 = new Wall("wall_02", wallOptions);

wallImages.initWall();
wallImages2.initWall();
```

It could be even better to embed initalization in a function, but this solution is probably the easiest if you simply want to have two `Wall` instances without learning much more about JS.

Comment: THX @Matti , I'll give it a test later, however I was hoping there's a way of "binding" without creating multiple options, I'm using var Array for different "walls"